# Composer update error on friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony-3.4

i wanted to install the following packages for the Symfony Framework 3.4 with help of the composer package manager:
friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle
guzzlehttp/psr8
php-http/guzzle6-adapter

I dont have much experience with composer. I saw that those packages are installable under Symfony 3.4 in a tutorial. I even tried installing every component of the bundle one by one, quitting with the bellow error message for example (guzzlehttp/psr7). When installations failed why are the packages then in my composer.json file under require ?

Here is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/http-cache": "^2.5.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle": "^2.6",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.5",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
```

I am getting this error message:
[Errror message](https://s2.imagebanana.com/file/190123/hTuNdkdF.PNG)

Error message installing (guzzlehttp/psr7):
[Errror message](https://s2.imagebanana.com/file/190123/V7KVAH6Z.PNG)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You executed `composer update`, so probably you have added packages manually in the composer.json

`composer update` won't change what is inside composer.json.

> upgrade: Upgrades your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md for mroe details.

Shortcut for "add if possible" is the command `composer require`

Exmaple:

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/http-cache
```

This will try to install the package. composer.* files will be updated only on successful installation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please look at my answer below ? I have explained a little bit more.